# How am I going to create a xml file using pullparser for hashmap

Tags: android, xml, xmlpullparser

I am trying to populate a xml file from user's input values. User will give 2 entries a Key and a value. And i have a model class which is a as below:

```
public class Person
{    private HashMap<String, String> hash = new HashMap<String, String>();

public Person()
{   }

public Person(String key, String val)
{ hash.put(key, val);   }


public String GetFirstName(String k)
{ return hash.get(k);   }

}
```

How to make a xml from this object of the class? and how to retrieve a value from xml against a key?

And i want the xml like this:

```
<AllEntries>
   <entry key="key1">value1</entry> 
   <entry key="key2">value2</entry> 
   <entry key="key3">value3</entry>
</AllEntries>
```

Comment: By populate, I assume you mean adding entries to an existing xml? Where will these entries go? In the root node? How do you want the entries to appear? like this `<person key="" value="" />`? We'll need a little more info.

Comment: ya should append to existing xml. And i want the xml like this: <AllEntries>
    <entry key="key1">value1</entry>
    <entry key="key2">value2</entry>
    <entry key="key3">value3</entry>
</AllEntries>

Comment: Maybe add that into the question and format it. It will help people answer and make the answer you get more specific to your problem. I'll take a look at it in my lunch break if someone hasn't solved it for you already. :)

Comment: that wud be great , coz i have to submit my project within 2 hrs :-)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a XML parser like Java [DOM](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/dom/readingXML.html) or [SAX](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/sax/parsing.html). The example below is Java DOM and shows you how to loop through the `HashMap` and add your entries to `your_xml.xml`.

```
File xmlFile = new File("your_xml.xml");
DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = dBuilder.parse(xmlFile);

for (Map.Entry<String, String> m : hash.entrySet()) {
    // Create your entry element and set it's value
    Element entry = doc.createElement("entry");
    entry.setTextContent(m.getValue());
    // Create an attribute, set it's value and add the attribute to your entry       
    Attr attr = doc.createAttribute("key");
    attr.setValue(m.getKey());
    entry.setAttributeNode(attr);
    // Append your entry to the root element
    doc.getDocumentElement().appendChild(entry);
}
```

Then you just need to save your document over the original file. Once your `Document` has been edited you'll probably want to [convert it to a String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2567416/document-to-string) to parse to your `OutputStream` of choice for saving.

Comment: whats hash & how to append my data in xml, i mean the new data with the old ? erm, plus how do add hashmap in xml?

Comment: @ShaonHasan - `hash` is your `HashMap` instance, as per your example code in the question. The above code adds the data into xml in the format you specified into an xml file called "your_file.xml". You need to specify the file location there.

Comment: I just added : Person hash = new Person("1","Shaon"); in the activity start. But hash.entrySet() is showing error on entryset. :-(

Comment: @ShaonHasan - `hash` needs to be an instance of a `HashMap`, not a `Person`. I think you need to read a good Java book or some tutorial to understand scope and the object IS-A relationship. I'm not sure I can talk you through all that to get the result you need. It's just too much for an answer on StackOverflow.

Comment: k.. added HashMap<String, String> hash = new HashMap<String, String>();
  hash.put("2", "Shaon");  inside activity. and ur code inside a try catch block also inside activity. did i do wrong again?

Comment: @ShaonHasan - That should do it, but you will still need to save the created document.

Comment: i have added these undernith ur code: TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
       Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
       DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
       StreamResult streamResult =  new StreamResult(new File("your_xml1.xml"));
       transformer.transform(source, streamResult);     but cant find any xml file in data folder inside the project.

Comment: @ShaonHasan - Any xmls in your project folders get compiled when the project is, so you can't change/replace them at runtime. You will have to [save a copy into android storage.](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html)